# is it possible to convert Func<T1,T2,TResult> to Func<T2,T1,TResult>

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

First, foo is a Func<T1,T2,TResult> object.
Is is possible do something like

```
Func<T2,T1,TResult> bar = ConvertFunction(foo);
```

thus convert Func<T1,T2,TResult> to Func<T2,T1,TResult>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```
Func<T2, T1, TResult> bar = (t2, t1) => foo(t1, t2);
```

That basically creates another delegate with switched parameters that internally simply calls the original delegate.
This is the *only way* to perform this kind of "conversion" if you only have a `Func<T1, T2, TResult>` and not a `Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>>`.

Comment: I don't see this a good answer for the question. This isn't a conversion: you're just invoking the func inside another func.

Comment: The result of this seems to be Func<T2,T1,TResult>, so it should be okay.

Comment: @RomainSertelon I would ask the OP to know if it fits his/her needs.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Indeed, it's simply delegating the call. So? You are free to post another answer - if you can come up with one :) If you really only have a `Func<T1, T2, TResult>` and not a `Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>>` this is the only way to do it - at least as far as I am aware.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I believe it could be done and get exactly what OP wants. I'll try to get it (sadly I'm @ work)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Can you give me a hint on how you think it can be done? I really don't think it is possible.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Maybe creating an expression from scratch and inspecting the source one with reflection to build the new expression. And then, trying to generalize it to a `Convert(...)` method. For sure, we would need a lot of overloads for this `Convert(...)`...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Anyway, I don't have the required time to experiment with this. If you can, go on.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: But that's the point: He doesn't have an expression in the first place! If he would have an expression, what you are saying is possible and actually the only correct way. But without an expression you have nothing to inspect.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You can still build the new func from an expression built based on source one.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Sorry, I have the feeling we are somehow talking about different things here. Again: *There is no source expression*. And the only expression you can build from a delegate is one that simply calls that delegate. So basically a more convoluted way of doing what my code already does.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: There is a reason why all the queryable methods take Expressions: They have to inspect the expression trees. *That is not possible with delegates*.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You've `foo`, which is the source func. I mean that, using some reflection, you can make the total conversion. Sure it's more complex to accomplish this approach, but once you've generalized it in an utility class or an extension method or who knows what, it can make the exact job required by the OP.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Nope, not going to work. Who says that `foo` points to a method on a class? It could be an anonymous method. Or simply accessing a property. Or all kinds of stuff. You would have to inspect the IL code, just like a decompiler. BTW: "The exact job required by the OP": He never specified that `foo` wasn't allowed to be called in the new delegate...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: the `foo` is a compiled delegate (be it a labda or a member of another class), you can't (even with reflection) disassemble it to swap the arguments and type params with current version of .NET. It may be possible with Roslyn, but that'd just be an overkill. I like Daniel's solution, it's a one-liner that most likely does the job.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yeah, I see, the problem is we wouldn't be able to get what's called inside the func. Meh!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Maybe the problem is that the goal of the OP could be accomplished using other approaches. Well, let's see if your answer fits what OP was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function:

```
class MyFuncConverter<T1, T2, TResult>
{
    static Func<T1, T2, TResult> _foo;

    public static Func<T2, T1, TResult> ConvertFunction(Func<T1, T2, TResult> foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
        return new Func<T2, T1, TResult>(MyFunc);
    }

    private static TResult MyFunc(T2 arg2, T1 arg1)
    {
        return _foo(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arg1 = 10;
    var arg2 = "abc";

    // create a Func with parameters in reversed order 
    Func<string, int, string> testStringInt = 
        MyFuncConverter<int, string, string>.ConvertFunction(TestIntString);

    var result1 = TestIntString(arg1, arg2);
    var result2 = testStringInt(arg2, arg1);

    // testing results
    Console.WriteLine(result1 == result2);
}

/// <summary>
/// Sample method
/// </summary>
private static string TestIntString(int arg1, string arg2)
{
    byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
        .GetBytes(arg2.ToString() + arg1);
    string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Remember that `Func<T1, T2, TResult>` has T1, T2 contravariant. I believe that your code would be invalid in a lot of scenarios,.

Comment: What is this? Can you explain usage of your class to solve OP issue.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I've updated my answer with a pretty self-explanatory usage.